# Describing a concept as exhibiting polysemy

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

I am writing an essay where I argue, in part, about the different meanings a concept can take depending on the context and/or the person it is being applied by. (In my case, it's the concept of 'goodness'/virtue).

I stumbled upon the following word which seemed to define the idea quite succinctly.

Dicitonary.com defines the word **Polysemy** as:

> a condition in which a single word, phrase, or concept has more than one meaning or connotation.

However, it seems that **polysemic** is not an actual word. Would it be correct to use it in this context, regardless of that fact. Or is there a better alternative?

The sentence:

> Bertolt Brecht introduces the polysemic nature of 'goodness' in his play...

Comment: "Polysemy" refers to the semantic range of a **_word_** (or lexeme), whereas "semantic field" refers to the range of words which can be subsumed under a single _**concept_**.  Dunno whether or not this helps, but I've just spent the last few hours doing my brain in trying to find a term or terms which can be applied to (1) the set of meanings which a word can take, as against (2) the set of words forming part of semantic group.  hyponym/hypernym can apply to (2), but I'm uneasy with these terms since they seem to postulate an either/or divide rather than a set (range, filed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is:

***[Polysemic](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/polysemic)*** (adjective):

> - having more than one meaning; having multiple meanings; also called [polysemous](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/polysemous)

(Dictionary.com)

Both adjectives are used, see [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=polysemic%2Cpolysemous&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpolysemic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpolysemous%3B%2Cc0)

Another less common variant is [polysemantic](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/polysemantic+word), see [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=polysemic%2Cpolysemous%2Cpolysemantic&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpolysemic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpolysemous%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpolysemantic%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Huh, interesting. I based it off of Microsoft Word's spellcheck and it considered the word incorrect (but polysemy was fine). Guess, I should've checked online first.