# Is there an adjective for a word that contains multiple connotations as implied by its contextual usage?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning-in-context, adjectives

I recognized in the process of writing this clause,

> Resulting in the discretion of death as we know it

That the “discretion of death” could encompass a range of semantic vectors depending on how one reads it in the context provided. If read from the point of view of death itself, the discretion takes on a different quality than if read from the point of view of those affected by death. In my efforts, I attempted to head ‘discretion’ with the awkward phrase ‘holistically representational,’ wishing to grapple the multidirectional nature of the ideally situated word I’m looking for.

Is there a single-word adjective that better, more accurately captures this sort of lexical ambiguity?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Your quoted clause sentence appears to imply a rather esoteric meaning for *discretion,* and the paragraph below it is not clear at all. **You** know what you're talking about: please try to explain it to people who do not have the advantage of your prior work.

Comment: It seems to me any "lexical ambiguity" in respect of "discretion of death" simply arises from the fact that it's not an established collocation with a known/agreed meaning. Is that an inherent part of what you're asking about? By which I mean - are you asking for a word to describe a "new permutation" of words that *some* people think has ***multiple meanings**?* And does it make any difference if some *other* people think the new permutation has ***no meanings at all**?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers It’s rather that I’m asking for a word to describe the multiple meanings some people receive from a permutation of words that has clearly derived linchpins in different branches of thought. I see that the fact of this collocation being my own construction, and not well-known hinders the accessibility of my question to potential responders. Thank you for the quick comments, I’ll try to correct the issues promptly

Comment: I'm not necessarily suggesting any of these are duplicates (mainly because I don't understand this question! :) but you might want to look at [Regular vs Irregular polysemy](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/586799/) and [Describing a concept as exhibiting polysemy](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/390747/). And perhaps [Single word to mean 'having more than one meaning'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/531912/), even though *your* question concerns multi-word combinations.